# Is there a way to set NetBeans to run Chrome Incognito as default browser?

Tags: browser, netbeans-8, incognito-mode

I am trying to set Chrome Incognito as default Browser, but I dont know how to do this.
I'm running NetBeans 8.0.2.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open options from top menu (Tools -> Options) then click on Edit button to the right of Web Browser selector and configure as in the screenshot. [image: screenshot]